# pyinstaller module not found fake_useragent

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

Module not found when executing pyinstaller distributed executable

Used hiddenimport and it gets imported but still not working

pyinstaller command :- `pyinstaller --hiddenimport flask --hiddenimport fake_useragent -F --add-data "templates;templates" main.py`

output after running dist/main.exe:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fake_useragent\utils.py", line 142, in load
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\mdreh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI193242\\fake_useragent\\data\\browsers.json'
Unable to find local data/json file or could not parse the contents using importlib-resources. Try pkg-resource next.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fake_useragent\utils.py", line 128, in load
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 22, in files
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 53, in get_package
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 44, in resolve
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent.data'
Could not find local data/json file or could not parse the contents using pkg-resource. Fallback to external resource.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fake_useragent\utils.py", line 128, in load
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 22, in files
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 53, in get_package
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 44, in resolve
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1206, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1178, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1142, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fake_useragent.data'
```

Not sure why it can't find the module `data` because when i run normal `.py` file it is working properly

Also `12631 INFO: Analyzing hidden import 'fake_useragent'` did not gave any error.

Perhaps `fake_useragent` require additional files, if so, please assist me

Comment: did you try running this command? -> pip install fake-useragent

Comment: requirement already satisified, if using pip, if i use this argument in pyinstaller it says fake-useragent not found

Answer (score 2):

Basically, pyinstaller cannot detect the files which are used by `Fake_UserAgent`, which are cache files, so one way to fix it is to disable those saved cache files

```
import fake_useragent

useragent = fake_useragent.UserAgent(use_external_data=True)
```

by passing `True`, we command useragent module to use external data which is not saved in our local computer

More info can be found [here](https://pypi.org/project/fake-useragent/)

Comment: While i upvoted, this no longer works as of Aug 2nd 2023 with the 1.2.0 update. Still running into this issue, luckily i dont need fake_useragent in my application so for the time being ive removed the import and its use in my application. If anyone knows another workaround please share